# Detecting a category page in the isCategoryPage method

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

I currently have an SCA website that has sub categories that need to display as a category page, and not a Product listing page.  (i.e. display the categories, not the products).

Currently, I have modified the isCategoryPage to override the Facets.Views.isCategoryPage such that it does this correctly.  However, when doing a search on the site - it breaks that page with a blank page.

I am currently stuck at figuring out how to detect if I am on a search page rather than a category page.

The code is thus:

```
...
        // @Overrides Facets.Views.isCategoryPage
        isCategoryPage: function isCategoryPage(translator) {
            var currentFacets = translator.getAllFacets();
            var categories = translator.getCategoryPath();

            if (<--IsSearchPage() === true --->) {
                return (_.keys(categories[categories.length-1].categories).length !== 0);
            } else {
                return (currentFacets.length === 1 &&
                    currentFacets[0].id === 'category' &&
                   categories &&
                    CategoryHelper.showCategoryPage(categories)
                );
            }
        },
...
```

As you can see the if statement is where I need a bit of help.

```
if (<--IsSearchPage() === true --->) {
```

What method, function, code would detect if the page is a search page.  Or if the page url has /search in the url.  (either would work).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper update, after much trial and error:

```
isCategoryPage: function isCategoryPage(translator) {
    var currentFacets = translator.getAllFacets();
    var categories = translator.getCategoryPath();

    if (categories) {
        return (_.keys(categories[categories.length-1].categories).length !== 0);
    } else {
        return (currentFacets.length === 1 &&
            currentFacets[0].id === 'category' &&
           categories &&
            CategoryHelper.showCategoryPage(categories)
        );
    }
},
```